# Traefik reverse proxy manipulates content-type header leading to MIME type error

Tags: reverse-proxy, mime-types, content-type, traefik

I have configured Traefik reverse proxy to connect to my application. When I hit my application directly (without any proxy) I am able to get all JS, CSS, HTML pages but if I try to connect to my application via Traefik reverse proxy I face MIME type error.

Basically Treafik proxy changes all content-type header values of response to text/plain value. I tried to change Traefik autodetect configuration to True and False but either of it didn't worked.

**traefik.toml**

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
loglevel = "INFO"
[accessLog]
    filePath = "access-log.log"
[log]
    filePath = "traefik-log.log"
[tracing]
  serviceName = "service_console"

# enable dashboard
[api]
    dashboard = true
    insecure = true


# Create entrypoint
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":8888"


# user file provider
[providers]
    [providers.file]
        filename = "traefik-dynamic.toml"
```

**traefik-dynamic.toml**

```
[http]

    # Create route for http
    [http.routers.router_console]
        entryPoints = ["http"]
        service = "service_console"
        rule = "Path(`/`)"

    # Create loadbalaner for serivces
    [http.services]
        [http.services.service_console.loadBalancer]
            [[http.services.service_console.loadBalancer.servers]]
                url = "https://172.18.80.32:1443/"
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rahul Kumbhar

Comment: I would help if you posted your traefik config file (or docker labels used)

Comment: @StefanoMozart I have updated my question with traefik config files. Any input will be appreciated.